# How do I fix incorrect public url on s3cmd response?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I am uploading a file to my S3 instance using s3cmd. When I run `s3cmd put test_py3.csv.gz s3://my.bucket/path/ --acl-public` after the upload it gives the public url as `http://my.bucket.my.bucket/path/test_py3.csv.gz`
instead of `http://my.bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/path/test_py3.csv.gz`

I have tested and confirmed that `http://my.bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/path/test_py3.csv.gz` works fine, the only issue seems to be that s3cmd is adding my bucket a second time instead of s3.amazonaws.com when it is displaying the public url string.

How can I make it display the correct public url?

Comment: It is probably assuming that you provided a domain name instead of a bucket name. These days, it is recommended to use the official [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`.

Comment: Hmm I see, what's the equivalent code to do this in awscli?

Comment: `aws s3 cp test_py3.csv.gz s3://my.bucket/path/ --acl public-read`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparantly not possible with s3cmd. It needs to be done with awscli and the command `aws s3 cp test_py3.csv.gz s3://my.bucket/path/ --acl public-read`